# how to mask a password and show the cursor movements in commandline in java?

Tags: java, masking, console.readline

I am trying to run a java application in console. Here is the code for username and password I used `console.readPassword()` and when I type my password in the console the cursor appears on the same same starting line and it remains in the same position until I enter the full password and click on <kbd>Enter</kbd> button.

```
    Console console = System.console();
    console.printf("Please enter your username: ");
    String username = console.readLine();
    console.printf(username + "\n");
    console.printf("Please enter your password: ");


    char[] passwordChars = console.readPassword();
    console.printf("Password entered was: %s%n", new String("#####"));
    String password = new String(passwordChars);
```

This code masks the password after the complete password is entered, but it does not show any cursor movements when the user enters their password.

My idea would be something like masking the password with special characters and the proper cursor movements which does not confuse the user. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: This is how most, if not all, consoles read passwords. It's an intended security feature so someone cannot see how long your password is

Comment: ok so there is no way to show cursor movements ?

Comment: Not if you are using the console class and its readPassword function.